# eclipse plugin perforce not showing when installed

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, perforce

When installing `perforce plugin` on `Eclipse Juno 4.2.2`, nothing happens. I am unable to see the additional tabs e.g. `'perforce'` or when wanting to import, I am unable to see p4v import option. I have tried installing `perforce v4.4, v4.3, v4.2, v3.7` - no luck. Though the eclipse GUI it shows that the plugin is installed. Using `JDK 1.6` / have reinstalled eclipse.

Any ideas? I have been spending hours on this with no luck.

Comment: it could be many things ? have you installed a prepackged zip ? or from an update site ?

Comment: Do you need to open a perforce perspective?

Comment: I have downloaded and installed the application through the eclipse gui - marketplace . I took the url for the repository from the perforce site. What can I try?. Also I need to import a project

Comment: Did you try restarting Eclipse and trying to add the Perforce perspective?

Comment: I managed to resolve the issue. The plugin has a requirement of java 1.6. In eclipse my java configuration was set to java 1.5. Changing this resolved it. Rather odd because i would of expected eclipse to not install the app if it is not compatible.